# Suitable datetime_format configuration of awslogs to upload audit.log

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm configuring the AWS CloudWatch client for linux (RHEL) to upload all important logs to CloudWatch. I'm stuck at configuring the client section for the audit.log. I keep getting the message

`... Fall back to current time ...  reason: timestamp could not be parsed ...`

I think the format of the logfile (the system default) is not suitable for parsing by the awslogs client. What's my best course of action? Is there a way to configure the awslogs client for the audit logfiles or should I change the format of the audit logfiles to better fit awslogs expectations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`audit.log` entries look like this:

```
type=ADD_USER msg=audit(1539364777.590:6): pid=2710 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=adding user id=500 exe="/usr/sbin/useradd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
```

The number with a period and a colon is the `epoch` and `audit id`. The audit id may be repeated in the file.

Unfortunately strftime doesn't have a standard epoch format (there's `%s`, but it isn't in the spec and isn't supported in python). And cwlogs.parser.DateTimeParser doesn't have a workaround for it. And cwlogs.util.epoch() doesn't ever work against the raw format. Grrr.

So, you need to use the awslogs default of sending an entry with the current time (instead of the log time).